# Printing file names with unicode characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I have a program which helps deal with some file manipulation tasks. It builds lists of files to work with like this:

```
useful_files = [file for file in os.listdir(self.operatingDirs[0])
                if re.match(this_task_re, file)]
```

Then it does stuff with them.  From time to time it tells the user what it is doing:

```
for file_name in useful_files:
    pub.sendMessage("LOG MESSAGE", msg = "Checking folders for %s" % file_name)
```

When European users use this program, it starts failing like this:

`File "usefulfilefolder.pyc", line 310, in _DeduceDropBoxFolders
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

on the line with the `sendMessage` call.

The error appears to be being generated by me attempting to insert the file name that I got from `os.listdirs` into the message string.

IE: It appears that the file name that I got from the file system can't be printed back out directly.

Is this correct?

How should I deal with this?

Note that I have to (I believe) retain the name that I got from listdirs so that I can use it in other file system operations to refer to the same file....

Thanks!

(note - I can't easily upgrade to Python3 at the moment due to libraries that aren't supported)

(edited to clarify the points made in comments below)

Comment: Can you give the code of your ``sendMessage`` method? I think you're doing some type of encoding (something like message.encode('utf-8')) that expects to receive ASCII.

Comment: A *decode* error usually indicates you are trying to combine unicode and string values somewhere; can you show us the full traceback?

Comment: I elaborated the traceback: the last line in the traceback is pointing to the line with the sendMessage call in it.   I presume that this means that I am combining unicode with string in this % statement.   How do I avoid doing this - I got the file_name from an os call.   I need (I believe) to leave it untouched so that I can use it to access the file later.   Do I need to process it in some way whenever I go to print it, like  msg = "blah %s" % sanitize(file_name) ?

Comment: I don't think the quoted code/error/line is accurate. You have a byte string filename (which is a bad start by the way—use unicode strings for filenames on Windows or you'll be unable to access anything outside of the locale code page) which according to the error you're implicitly decoding to Unicode. But the line quoted with the `sendMessage` call has only byte strings and so cannot produce a `UnicodeDecodeError` (though the implementation of `sendMessage` itself might). What is `sendMessage`—is it supposed to  support Unicode arguments?

Comment: I am starting to think that for some reason the backtrace is truncated there, too.   What I have established is that the file names that os.listdir is returning are strs, not unicodes.   When the files names have non-ascii characters in them, something is failing to decode this str.    sendMessage is from the pubsub library.   I am starting to think that is either in there, or even more possibly, in the receiver of the message that the actual error is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this turned out to be:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make you file a right encoding, like utf-8. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Then, use some_string.decode('the encoding') where you error occur.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this answer implies you think that I am reading from the file?

I am not reading from the file - I get a name from os.listdir, and attempt to insert it into a string.   This is the point at which things fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I do this sort of thing:

```
file_name =  os.listdir(problem_dir)[0]
print "I looked at %s" % file_name
```

I get the unicode error.  Is this really yuk?   It seems to me it is: I can't safely print something I get from os.listdir()!

If I do this sort of thing:

```
file_name =  os.listdir(problem_dir)[0]
print "I looked at %s" % file_name.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

then it works.

So this is some sort of answer, but I really hope that there's a better way?

I'm finding it hard to test, because I don't have unicode file names on my machine, so I keep having to iterate with a cooperative user.    I'm wondering: would it be valid to do

```
file_name =  os.listdir(problem_dir)[0].decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

and use that name everywhere later.   Will I be able to rely on the fact that

`os.path.exists(file_name)` would be true after doing that decode?   (It would be nice if true, but it would surprise me)

TVMIA!

Comment: I realise that this "answer" is mistaken in one thing I thought was happening: I don't have unicode file names at all, I have file names that are byte strings, which might not be ascii, and this is what os.listdir is returning, and this is why I have to decode them with sys.getfilesystemencoding().   Otherwise something else tries to decode them as ascii....